# Lipschitz continuity implies continuity in metric spaces

Tags: continuity, lipschitz-functions

I have to prove that a function $f: M \rightarrow N$ where $(M,d)$ and $(N,p)$ are metric spaces is continuous, given it is Lipschitz continuous. 
What I found so far:

Let $\epsilon>0$ and $\delta=\epsilon/K$

Since $f$ is Lipschitz continuous, there exists a $K<\infty$ such that $p(f(x),f(y)) \le Kd(x,y) = K\delta < \epsilon$

Hence $p(f(x),f(y)) < \epsilon$ for $d(x,y)<\delta$ and thus $f$ is continuous.

It feels like it is too easy and I forgot something. Can someone help me?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Small issue: You cannot set $\delta = \epsilon/K$ before you've introduced $K$.